# Extra large array

Tags: c#, gcallowverylargeobjects, large-data

I have to operate with two-dimensional array(s) with size 34000x34000 items for math calculations.
Obvious problem - is impossibility of CLR to store such big parts of data in memory. I tried to use `MemoryMappedFile`, but it fails too while I'm trying to create viewer for the object: `MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor()`. Are there any other already existed ways to store large arrays? ('cause I havent' much time for trying to implement custom large data storage)
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) configuration element allows for over-2-Gb-arrays for 64-bit processes. You might give that a try.

Also, see if [sparse arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) can help you:

> A sparse array is an array in which most of the elements have the default value (usually 0 or null). The occurrence of zero-value elements in a large array is inefficient for both computation and storage.

Comment: Thanks, this solution suits best for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can use the `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true|false"/>`-config element. It configures the GC so that it allows objects larger than 2GB in memory. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx), section "My app works on large datasets (uses objects > 2GB)", respectively [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=VS.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` consider to use jagged array instead - dealing with one huge piece of memory (I guess about 10GB for doubles)  definitely require some additional effort.

```
YourType[][] array = Enumerable.Range(0, 34000).Select(_ => new YourType[34000]).ToArray();
```

Note that you definitely need x64 process to use such array - make sure to explicitly build you exe with x64 only.

Comment: I've tried, this code throws an OutOfMemoryException for me on a ~6000 element

Comment: @dotFive I bet you've missed "need x64 process to use such array" remark. Anyway good that gcAllowVeryLargeObjects  worked for you (also I don't see how one worked and another did not).